# Web player to use with SHOUTcast

Tags: streaming, flash, shoutcast

I'm looking for a web player to play a music stream from a SHOUTcast server.

I setup a SHOUTcast DNAS 2.0 Server on CentOS.  SHOUTcast can stream music to Windows Media player and winamp; however, I want to be able to stream music to an html pop-up window with a modern browser such as firefox, chrome, IE, safari.

A Flash or HTML based player would be great that can handle loop playback and audio/mpeg streams; open source if possible.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Here you go. First google result for shoutcast flash player. Also, I use it, and it works well. http://www.wavestreaming.com/servers/flash-streaming/shoutcast-player.php

Comment: @Mauricio, I believe this is appropriate for SO

Comment: humm.. thought I saw this player yesterday in a youtube video, I'll check it out.

Comment: How to play SHOUTcast?http://stackoverflow.com/a/8833346/265167

Comment: Title of current song playing would be very useful :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are some free flash players with anti memory leak technology from Museter.com
http://www.museter.com/SHOUTcast_Hosting_Online_Radio_Flash_Player.php

Comment: Checked out the skins in the link and they look pretty cool. I'll plug one in, post tomorrow how it went :)