# Winamp Shoutcast streaming wordpress

Tags: wordpress, shoutcast, internet-radio

Is there a way to add some kind of player into Wordpress which stream Winamp radio?

```
http://94.127.2.98:8000/radio.m3u
http://94.127.2.98:8000/radio
```

Comment: Solution here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823185/web-player-to-use-with-shoutcast

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use JW Player for our radio station [site](http://mayumibeats.com/)

Download the files here http://www.longtailvideo.com/players

Youre code will look like this:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js"></script>       
    <script type="text/javascript">
      var flashvars =
      {
        'file':               'http://94.127.2.98:8000/;stream.nsv',
        'title':              'Your Stream',
        'type':               'sound',
        'duration':           '99999',
        'frontcolor':         'FFFFFF',  // text & icons                  
        'backcolor':          '2d5c88',  // playlist background           
        'lightcolor':         'C286BA',  // selected text/track highlight 
        'screencolor':        'FFFFFF',  // screen background            
        'id':                 'playerID',
        'autostart':          'true'
      };

      var params =
      {
        'allowfullscreen':    'false',
        'allowscriptaccess':  'always',
        'bgcolor':            '#FFFFFF'
      };

      var attributes =
      {
        'id':                 'playerID',
        'name':               'playerID'
      };

      swfobject.embedSWF("url_player_source_path/player.swf", 'player', '268', '20', '9.0.124', false, flashvars, params, attributes);
    </script>
     <div id="playercontainer" class="playercontainer"><a id="player" class="player" href="http://www.adobe.com/shockwave/download/download.cgi?P1_Prod_Version=ShockwaveFlash">Get the Flash Plugin to listen to music.</a></div>
```